# Edge fails requests to the same domain due to CORS

Tags: cors, single-page-application, microsoft-edge

My SPA application servet at example.com makes requests to example.com/api. AFAIK this should not require any `access-control-allow-origin` headers since the origin and the target are the same.

However i get the following error;

> SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'https://example.com' did not find
>   'https://example.com' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response
>   header for cross-origin  resource at
>   'https://example.com/iam/blablablabla'

This application works perfectly on Chrome or Firefox. It fails only on Edge. Is there something I am missing here? Can you show me some directions to understand the problem I have?

P.S; I went forward and added the domain as allowed CORS origin on my server, too. It didn't work either.

Comment: Can you tell us the request headers you're sending and the response headers you're getting?

Comment: If this is a request which requires preflight then there is a bug in Edge which causes this issue. Can you check if adding the "https://example.com/iam/blablablabla" to trusted zone in the Internet Options solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and went through the painstaking process of finding a fix.

This is related to a bug in Edge's fetch implementation in versions 42.17434.  This is fixed in version 44.17763 (November 2018 and beyond).  You can find your Edge version by clicking the ellipsis in the upper right, clicking "settings", and scrolling to the bottom.

The core of this issue is that while most browser implementations send a default option of `credentials: 'same-origin'` when the credentials option is omitted, Edge does not.  You should be able to fix this for old Edge builds by adding the credentials same-origin option to your request:

```
fetch(url, { credentials: 'same-origin' });
```

Related Edge issue tickets:

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19851173/
- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7984069/